# Installing Delphi package gives error missing BDS.INI

Tags: delphi, migration, package

I migrated a package from Delphi 6 to Delphi 10.2 and the package built successfully. But when I try to install the package it gives error BDS.INI missing.
I tried to remove some .pas files until the error goes away and then it installed successfully. I cannot find anything related to BDS.INI in the pas file that causes the problem.
There is Delphi 6 and Delphi 10.2 installed on the same system. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you started debugging this and cutting down to a [mcve]. Keep going. Make that [MCVE] and then we can help.

Comment: Look for Application.Exename or ParamStr(0) in combination with "ini" in the package code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If UpperCase(ExtractFileName(system.paramStr(0))) = 'DELPHI32.EXE' Then Begin
There were some instances of this code. I changed 'DELPHI32.EXE' to  'BDS.EXE'  and the package installed successfully. Thanks for the hint @UweRaabe

Comment: This bears no relation to detail in the question and can't be of any use to anybody in the future. As SO is a resource for all, it is best to remove the posts.

Comment: I tried to cut down the code to minimal and found that there were two pas files causing the problem. When I searched for instances of ParamStr(0) in those files, I came across the code where there was some code like ExtractFileName(system.paramStr(0)) which was compared with 'DELPHI32.exe'. Since my code was migrated to 10.2, I changed it to 'BDS.exe' and it worked. It may help someone out there.

Comment: If the question can't be answered by anyone but the asker, using detail only they have, it is pretty much always worthless to others.